# how to get more stable locations rather than more accurate ones

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-maps, fusedlocationproviderapi

my app uses the fusedlocationprovider api to retrieve the user current location and showing a marker on the map every second using the following code

```
locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
            interval = 1000
            fastestInterval = 1000
            priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }
```

the problem is that the location I am getting , just not that accurate so the marker keeps  moving even the phone is not. so after looking on the internet I find out that google says that there api accuracy is about 6 - 10 meters . so now what I want to accomplish is to get a stable location update , it does not matter if it is only estimated . what's important is to show the marker  a little bit steady on the map.